# How do I effectively use navigation links in a simple SwiftUI app?

Tags: navigation, swiftui

I am really, really new at writing code for SwiftUI! I have been trying to create an app to use for golf and all I want in the first instance is to show a Hole by Hole list with a link to a swift file or image that shows that hole. So, clicking on Hole 1 in the list takes me to a new screen that shows the details of that Hole 1 plus image.

Here's the code so far:

```
import SwiftUI

struct NavigationLists: View {
    struct DetailView: View {
        let holes: String
        var body: some View {
            Text(holes)
        }
    }

    let holes = ["Hole 1", "Hole 2", "Hole 3", "Hole 4", "Hole 5", "Hole 6", "Hole 7", "Hole 8",     "Hole 9", "Hole 10", "Hole 11", "Hole 12", "Hole 13", "Hole 14", "Hole 15", "Hole 16", "Hole 17", "Hole 18"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(holes, id: \.self) { holes in
                NavigationLink(
                destination: DetailView(holes: holes)) {
                    Text(holes)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Hole by Hole")
        }
    }
}

struct NavigationLists_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationLists()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your specific question? (re: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)). Include the specific behavior that you are trying to achieve, and what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you look through the Building Lists and Navigation tutorials over [here](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation).

> You’ll create views that can show information about any landmark, and dynamically generate a scrolling list that a user can tap to see a detail view for a landmark. To fine-tune the UI, you’ll use Xcode’s canvas to render multiple previews at different device sizes.

This should get you going:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Hole: Hashable {
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var imageName: String
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @State var hole: Hole

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: self.hole.imageName)
            Text(self.hole.title)
            Text(self.hole.description)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let holes: [Hole] = [
        Hole(title: "Hole 1", description: "Hole 1 Description", imageName: "square.and.arrow.up"),
        Hole(title: "Hole 2", description: "Hole 2 Description", imageName: "square.and.arrow.up.fill"),
        Hole(title: "Hole 3", description: "Hole 3 Description", imageName: "pencil.circle"),
        Hole(title: "Hole 4", description: "Hole 4 Description", imageName: "pencil.circle.fill")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(self.holes, id: \.self) { hole in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(hole: hole)) {
                    Text(hole.title)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Hole by Hole")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Fuzz - that input was excellent. I erased systemName and my hole image came through. I am very grateful for your guidance here.